# How to set fields non-nullable for JOOQ POJO

Tags: kotlin, gradle, jooq, pojo, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have this DDL

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
    id       bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name string NOT NULL
);
```

org.jooq.codegen.KotlinGenerator generates such a class:

```
data class Users(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var name: String? = null,
): Serializable
```

I expect non-nullable fields to be non-nullable, like:

```
data class Users(
    var id: Long,
    var name: String,
): Serializable
```

I only use these settings:

```
    generate.apply {
                isRecords = true
                isDaos = true
                isPojosAsKotlinDataClasses = true
                isSpringAnnotations = true
                isPojos = true
            }
```

Jooq ver. 3.15.10

How do I configure the generator so that the fields are non-nullable?

Answer (score 1):

As of jOOQ 3.17, there are pending feature requests to add some additional convenience at the price of correctness to generated classes:

- [#10212](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/10212) Add option to handle nullability in KotlinGenerator
- [#12934](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12934) Null-safe views of columns known to be non-null

The main reason why this hasn't been implemented yet is the many ways such non-nullability promises can break in the event of using operators like `LEFT JOIN`, `UNION` and many others, in case of which an expression that appears to be non-null will produce `null` values nonetheless.

While #10212 is very hard to get right, #12934 might be a compromise to be implemented soon, given that it affects only generated `data class` types, which can be used on a 1:1 basis by users who understand the tradeoffs.